# TensorFlow custom model optimizer returning NaN. Why?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I want to learn optimal `weights` and `exponents` for a custom model I've created:

```
weights = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([t.num_features, 1], dtype=tf.float64))
exponents = tf.Variable(tf.ones([t.num_features, 1], dtype=tf.float64))

# works fine:
pred = tf.matmul(x, weights)

# doesn't work:
x_to_exponent = tf.mul(tf.sign(x), tf.pow(tf.abs(x), tf.transpose(exponents)))
pred = tf.matmul(x_to_exponent, weights)

cost_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(pred-y_))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(t.LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cost_function)
```

The problem is that whenever there is a <s>negative value</s> zero in `x` the optimizer returns the weight as `NaN`. If I simply add 0.0001 when x = 0 then everything works as expected. But should I really have to do this? Shouldn't the TensorFlow optimizer have a way to handle this?

I've noticed Wikipedia shows no [activation functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) where x is taken to an exponent. Why isn't there an activation function that looks as below Image?
[image]

For the above image I'd like my program to learn that the correct exponent is 0.5.

Comment: Are you sure you want weights to be an **exponent**? This can easily go to infintiy. Please include your whole code too.

Comment: Yes -- I want to learn what exponent I have to take my input data to in order to make the correct predictions. The exponent will usually be between 0-1 so shouldn't go to infinity.. For example if the above image was the model we are trying to predict the correct exponent we need to learn is 0.5.

Comment: @lejlot I've updated the code to show more clearly what works and what doesn't work. There was also a mistake that I corrected.

Comment: Do you mean you get nan whenever x is zero?  That would be expected, since the gradient there is infinity as shown in your graph.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving yes, you are correct. The problem is with x = 0. If I simply add 0.0001 to each x = 0 it seems to solve the problem and everything works as expected. Does the TensorFlow optimizer have a way to handle this situation without me having to manually add 0.0001?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct behavior on TensorFlow's part, since the gradient is infinity there (and many computations that should mathematically be infinity end up NaN due to indeterminate limits).

If you want to work around the problem, a slightly generalized version of gradient clipping may work.  You can get the gradients via `Optimizer.compute_gradients`, manually clip them via something like

```
safe_grad = tf.clip_by_value(tf.select(tf.is_nan(grad), 0, grad), -lim, lim)
```

and then pass the clipped gradients to `Optimizer.apply_gradients`.  The clipping will be necessary to not explode for values near the singularity, where the gradient may be arbitrarily large.

**Warning**: There is no guarantee that this will work, especially for deeper networks where the nans may pollute large swaths of the network.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I will refer back here when my understanding has improved and I am ready to implement such a solution.